# iOS Cocoapods file not found error

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, jenkins, cocoapods

I working with the project with objective-c and Swift code combined. When i'm installing cocoa pods from Jenkins getting error file not found.
I want to install ObjectMapper for swift and remaining for Objective-C.

```
 target ‘XXXXXXX’ do
 pod 'GoogleAnalytics’
 pod 'GoogleTagManager’,’~> 3.15.0’
 pod 'KeychainItemWrapper'
 pod 'Base64nl'

 use_frameworks!
 pod 'ObjectMapper'
end
```

**But i am getting error like - fatal error : 'Base64.h' file not found
    #import "Base64.h"**

But base64 pod got installed in my project and source file also there in my PODs folder.

Comment: these are wrong `pod 'GoogleAnalytics’
 pod 'GoogleTagManager’,’~> 3.15.0’` use like as `pod 'GoogleAnalytics'
 pod 'GoogleTagManager','~> 3.15.0'`

Comment: and `use_frameworks!` in below the target

Comment: i want to install latest from repo, It was working before, I have added swift library last week, then onwards getting issue.   Before that no issues without version number.

Comment: tried use_frameworks! in below the target  also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you use use_frameworks! in your Podfile, you don't have to include every Objective-C pod in your bridging header. You only have to do this, if the pod is distributed as a static library, not as a framework.**

> With the use_frameworks! directive, you can now consume Swift
>   libraries using CocoaPods! After you've added use_frameworks! to your
>   Podfile, you can directly import Swift libraries from your Swift code
>   using the framework name (i.e. import AFNetworking).
>
> Potential Issue: Unfortunately, all Objective-C Pods haven't been
>   updated to work with the new dynamic frameworks behavior. You might
>   come across certain Objective-C Pods that no longer build after adding
>   the use_frameworks! directive. In these cases you can either not use
>   the use_frameworks! directive (you'll now need to create a bridging
>   header) or manually edit the offending Pod to help it find the headers
>   (as done in the linked issue).
>   [Cocoapods](https://guides.codepath.com/ios/CocoaPods)

Comment: i have created bridging header also, and imported all the related headers. But still same issue.

Comment: try this steps : 1. Press Cmd + option + shift + k to clean your build folder
2. Run pod install
3. Delete the lines in your bridging header where it tells you that the header files are not found and use a simple import statement whenever you want to use that module in one specific Swift file,

Comment: thank you so much @KKRocks, thats right. Both won't work together. Issue fixed.

Comment: @Anuska Welcome ... enjoy coding